# Webpack 5 not showing images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, webpack

I have a vue 3 app where I set up webpack 5 eventually. As I see I eliminated all my issues now the only thing remains is that it does not load my svg-s and images when I run the webpack serve script in dev mode. How can I configure webpack so that it would bundle my svg-s from the scr/assets folder?

my webpack config:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const mode = process.env.VUE_APP_MODE || 'not-fullstack';

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: '@vue/runtime-dom',
      '@': path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
    fallback: { crypto: false, stream: false },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'vue-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'images/[name].[hash].[ext]',
        },
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              encoding: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/index.html'),
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new CopyPlugin([
      { noErrorOnMissing: true, from: './src/assets', to: 'images' },
    ]),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env),
      'process.env.VUE_APP_MODE': JSON.stringify(mode),
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
};
```

And I reference my svg-s in my Vue component like this:

```html
<img src="../../assets/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
```

As you can see I tried with the copy-webpack-plugin, maybe I just configured it wrong.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The config in webpack5 changed a lot

```js
{
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              encoding: false,
            },
```

This is not working anymore. The url-loader is even removed from the npm packages.

The current way is found in the documentation

https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images

Comment: Mike van Eckendonk,

Thank you for the official link, it is working fine with the sugguested change in Official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my original auto generated file by webpack cli from

```
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            type: "asset", // or "asset/resource"
        },
```

to

```
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            loader: 'file-loader',
        },
```

which then resolved my issue. According to my theory, the 'asset/resource' type is broken, because when i switched from 'asset/resource' type to file-loader, everything started to work without any issues. I also tried to debug and print the image object in console which was undefined.

Webpack version 5.75.0